# Creating a struct with a generic trait for field. Expected struct<trait> found struct<type that implements said trait>

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a struct that has a `BufWriter` that uses the `Write` trait, so that this struct could have a buffered writer that can be anything that implements that trait: `File`, `Stream`, etc. But I'm having an issue in my function that creates the struct saying that I have `mismatched types`. Here is an example code with the same issue.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};

pub struct BufWriterStruct<W: Write> {
    pub writer: Option<BufWriter<W>>,
}

impl <W: Write>BufWriterStruct<W> {
    pub fn new(filename: &str) -> BufWriterStruct<W> {
        BufWriterStruct {
            writer: Some(BufWriter::new(File::create(filename).unwrap())),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tmp = BufWriterStruct::new("tmp.txt");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3cb9bffbf82c1b4ffa44&version=stable)

with the error

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `BufWriterStruct<W>`,
    found `BufWriterStruct<std::fs::File>`
```

If instead I change my `new` function to instead take a parameter that implements the `Write` trait and use that when creating `BufWriter`, it works fine.

I feel like the former should be possible to do somehow.

Comment: Why do you think the first way should be possible? A `BufWriterStruct<W>` return value means that the caller gets to choose what the function returns, but that's clearly not what happens in your method.

Comment: Well in my actual case, I pass another parameter that would tell it what type to create. Like it would pass in a string like stream, file, etc, and the new would create that. 
I just wanted new to do everything (create file/stream, do whatever inside it needs to, etc).

I could just move the creation of file/stream outside of new though.

But the more I think about it, I don't think the way I want to do it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in mixing generic and specific:

```
impl <W: Write>BufWriterStruct<W> {
    pub fn new(filename: &str) -> BufWriterStruct<W> {
        BufWriterStruct {
            writer: Some(BufWriter::new(File::create(filename).unwrap())),
        }
    }
}
```

Here, your instance of `BufWriter` should accept a `W: Write`, which is decided *by the caller*, yet the function actually creates a `File`.

Let the caller decide, instead:

```
impl <W: Write> BufWriterStruct<W> {
    pub fn new(writer: W) -> BufWriterStruct<W> {
        BufWriterStruct {
            writer: Some(BufWriter::new(writer)),
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this will change invocation a bit:

```
fn main() {
    let tmp = BufWriterStruct::new(File::create("tmp.txt").unwrap());
}
```

And then [it'll work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f93dcc22f29b1bdbef4b&version=stable).

Answer (score 1):

```
impl <W: Write>BufWriterStruct<W> {
    pub fn new(filename: &str) -> BufWriterStruct<W>
```

This signature means that the following code would be valid:

```
let tmp : BufWriterStruct<Stdout> = BufWriterStruct::new("tmp.txt");
```

However this would clearly not work with your implementation of `new`, as it produces a `BufWriterStruct<File>`, not `<StdOut>`. If you want to return a `BufWriterStruct<File>`, you should declare your `new` function accordingly:

```
pub fn new(filename: &str) -> BufWriterStruct<File>
```

However, this change alone will leave the `W` parameter on the `impl` block unconstrained, and the compiler will be unable to infer a type for it. The best solution for this would be to put the `new` method on a non-generic `impl`:

```
impl BufWriterStruct<File> {
    pub fn new(filename: &str) -> BufWriterStruct<File> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that Rust doesn't support overloading (methods with the same name but different parameter lists), so if you had two `impl` blocks on the same type (disregarding generic parameters) each with a method named `new`, you'd get an error when trying to invoke one of them (as of Rust 1.4.0, merely defining methods with the same name in separate `impl` blocks is not a compile-time error). Therefore, you might wish to use a more explicit name than `new`.

Comment: Yeah. I think they way I want to do it is not possible. 
I think I'm just going to change it to where I pass a parameter that implements the `Write` trait. Then I can use it on `File`, `Stream`, etc.