# Why does my FooGen type not satisfy the RefGen trait bound?

Tags: generics, rust

I have this code that uses generics.

```
trait RefGen {
    fn gen () -> String;
}

struct FooGen;

impl RefGen for FooGen {
    fn gen () -> String {
        "foo".to_owned()
    }
}

struct Facade<R: RefGen> {
    gen: R
}

impl<R: RefGen> Facade<R> {
    fn new() -> Facade<R> {
        Facade {
            gen: FooGen
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder why Rust is telling me I can't use a `FooGen` for a `RefGen`. It certainly implements `RefGen`.

The exact error message is:

```
expected `Facade<R>`,
found `Facade<FooGen>`
```

Here is a playpen: http://is.gd/oBIB1o

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/31490913/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/31060851/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/33812706/155423 or (insert more search results here).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
impl<R: RefGen> Facade<R> {
  fn new(gen: R) -> Facade<R> {
    Facade {
      gen: gen
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure about the precise terms to explain this, but here it goes: in your code, the type `R` is determined *inside* the `new` function. However, Rust requires you to provide the type from *outside* the function. Check out the following example:

```
// This doesn't typecheck
fn foo1<T: Clone>() -> T {
    "hi"
}

// This works
fn foo2<T: Clone>(x: T) -> T {
    x
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32551408/2110623) for a more detailed explanation